# In asp.net how to view same image that we selected in another page using datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am doing a shopping cart project using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 using C#.

There are 3 pages

1. mobilecart
2. viewmobiledetails
3. orderedpage

On `mobilecart.aspx` there is a data list which contains image button so that it can show top 6 images from database.

If a user clicks that image it would go to `viewmobiledetails.aspx`. Up to here everything is working fine.

What I want is after clicking the image the `viewmobiledetails.aspx` should show the same image that user clicked/selected

Also when clicking buy now link `orderpage.aspx` should show the product selected name quantity and price

Comment: use a querry string ie in the url put viewmobiledetails.aspx?itemid=itemid and then in the page you are loading use request.querrystring["itemid"] or even use a formview to load the details you need

Comment: can you please say the code

Comment: I already have.... at the end of your url when you are navigating (either from a hyperlink of from a response.redirect("URL") place an ID in the query string like in the example above and then use request.querrystring["ID"] to get it back again, that's all there is to it, might want to google passing variables through a url if you are having trouble

Answer (score 0):

first i would like to say i dont really like the question because it seems you are looking for the whole solution and not do the work by your self, but as it also seems you are new to the world, so ill try to help, before you start to write code you should always write 
on "paper" what is going to happen where how, and of course how you store your data in DB, this will help you with your coding latter and will prevent pitfalls.

after that being said, you need to switch your thinking to object oriented thinking for example, your product your going to show in cart should be in DB something like:

```
ID, Name, ImageUrl, Price, Department
```

then you need to have a resource lib that contains all your images.

then as the user comment you, you can pass id of product in query string or in view state or the session or even a cookie ( as i said i dont want to do all the work for you, think by your self what u need and use it ) and from that u can call all the data you need from db ( and of course you should consider caching your site to prevent running to db for each request.

i hope this helps you.